# Defualt UIViewTable View showing left and right spacing - xCode 7.3.1 and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a simple table view and i can see by default some spaces on left and right as below marked in red , Can anyone please suggest why these spaces appear.

[image]

Comment: Check your constraints for any errors. You might have not unchecked the `constrain to margins` checkbox, which means the system adds some margin to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the default `layoutMargin`.

You can change it in the interface builder.

To disable it globally you can do:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    override public var layoutMargins: UIEdgeInsets {
        get { return UIEdgeInsetsZero }
        set { }
    }
}
```